# Growth of a fast minded person

Tags: humans

Suppose there is a person born with mind and eyes working three times faster than those of a common person, meaning he sees and ears like in a movie with speed set to 1/3.

How would the psychological and social development of this person be compared to a common one.

Comment: So a normal person sees 1 second of events in 1 second. This fast person sees 3 seconds of events in 1 second. How does this work?

Comment: everything including sound looks like being in slow  motion

Comment: @Jão That makes no sense because nobody knows how other people see the world. Slow motion for you is slow motion for someone else whether they are thinking more than you.

Comment: Not like this will prevent him from seeing or hearing anything, so his brain will just adjust to it. He will talk slowly to other people, even if he can talk like an auctioneer.

Answer (score 2):

**If by development you mean from birth, then not much difference.**

Sure he would have faster reaction speeds but he would still learn how to communicate based on his environment. Since we all communicate essentially the same he would have to learn to do so as well. Babies are great at this.

It's a lot like this: how do you know I perceive blue the same way you perceive blue(same shade)? We both know its blue because we learned to call that color blue but that doesn't mean you see it the same way I do. This difference in perspective doesn't really impact our understanding because that understanding is agreed upon communally and accepted by us at some point as a fact.

**If you mean more like some adult suddenly woke up like that then yes there would be significant challenges.**

They would have to relearn how to communicate. They would have to relearn fine motor control. It would have similar symptoms as the after effects of a stroke except for higher memory loss.

**PS this is all under the assumption that mind is working 3X faster.**

Note: There is some biological precedence for this in humans. When we are encountered with a dire situation our bodies can trigger an adrenal response. When this happens; time can appear to move slowly, this is because our brains have kicked into high gear diverting focus to the processing of stimuli. Our reaction time increases as well. There is a lot more to this then just the change in perception of time. [here's a starting point](https://sites.psu.edu/siowfa15/2015/10/02/do-we-seem-to-have-superpowers-in-life-or-death-situations/)

Comment: So all the great athletes whose performance involves superior reaction time may already be examples of this accelerated visual and evaluative processing.  Wonder what tests could be devised to see if that is true.

Comment: Actually there was a study done to look into that aspect. What they found was what many pro athletes describe as "in the zone" was in many cases an adrenal state. But we cant sustain this state, there's a reason why standard framerate for movies and games is roughly 31FPS because that's how humans normally perceive time.